# How to change "mode" when adding a specific type of object?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using fabricjs 1.7.20 and have "select" and "draw" modes. How can I make it so that when I  add text (with the button, while still in draw mode) it sets the mode to the select mode so that I can edit the text object immediately?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
  backgroundColor: "#fff"
});
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(300);

// Add text
function Addtext() {
  var text = new fabric.IText("Tap & type", {
    fontSize: 30,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    textAlign: "center"
  });
  canvas.add(text);
  canvas.setActiveObject(text);
}

// Modes
$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Addtext()">Add Text</button>
<button id="draw">Draw Mode</button>


<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enterEditing()` from text methods, and also a selectAll() if you need to.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
  backgroundColor: "#fff"
});
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(300);

// Add text
function Addtext() {
  var text = new fabric.IText("Tap & type", {
    fontSize: 30,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    textAlign: "center"
  });
  canvas.add(text);
  canvas.setActiveObject(text);
  text.enterEditing();
  text.selectAll();
  text.renderCursorOrSelection();  // or canvas.renderAll();
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
}

// Modes
$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Addtext()">Add Text</button>
<button id="draw">Draw Mode</button>


<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. In what instance might I need to include the selectAll()?

Comment: that depends on you is an option to have the text all selected.